# Button not being created programatically in dojo

Tags: javascript, button, dojo

I am using dojo version 1.6.1 and am trying to create a button. However, when I create the button programatically it doesn't show up correctly. It gives me a bullet point then the label of the button and then a small button (Weird!). Now I am new to dojo and I am sure I am missing something very basic. Here's my code for the button:    cript> 
    dojo.require("dijit.dijit");
    dojo.require("dijit.form.Button");

```
dojo.addOnLoad(function() {
    var button = new dijit.form.Button({
        label: "Click Me!"},"buttonNode");  
        button.startup();
});
```

I think it's worth mentioning that firebug doesn't show any errors!

Comment: your buttonNode exists and visible ?

Comment: yes!`<button id="buttonNode" type="button"></button>` this is what I am doing. Isn't that right?

Comment: <div id="buttonNode"></div> can solve the problem?

Comment: Tried that already ... didn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Dojo is obviously parsing your document (it is replacing your <button> with lots of funky HTML), it sounds like you have simply forgotten to include the CSS, or to put a theme class on your body tag (or another tag that encloses the button).

First make sure you have included a theme with something like:

```
<style type="text/css">
    @import url("your_dojo_path/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css");
</style>
```

and (since I'm using the claro theme here):

```
<body class="claro">...</body>
```